# Unwanted deformation by changing the pose of armature

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have a mesh (an operation table), like a normal operation table, just the top part(cushion part) can be bent and because of that, I put an armature inside the mesh.
What I want to have at the end is that the top part of the table can be bent, but the bottom part, the cantilever, shouldn't be deformed when I rotate the bone of the top part (x-axis top when you see it at the pic). The problem is that when I rotate the top part, the bottom part of the mesh is actually moving along the deformation of the top part of the mesh. How can I set the armature so that the bottom part isn't deformed along?

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33758)
[image: armature]

This is the bone (It won't show even with the X-Ray mode)
[image: deformed mesh]
The bottom part (the reverse T part of the table shouldn't be deformed - Just stay like it is).
  How should I put the weight or edit the armature? I haven't got the hang of weight of the armature.

Comment: Did you apply the scale , rotation and location?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I only applied rotation if that is what you mean, isn't it?

Comment: ohh ... yea , Press Cntrl + A , apply the scale

Comment: em. No difference  if I do that...

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking, could you please explain "*mesh deforms like there's no other day*"? thank you!

Comment: Could you post a .blend file, it would really really help us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: ;) That's just a bit of my bad wording... First I had a mesh and put the armature in the inside it. What I wanna get at the end is that only the above part of the object(the table/cushion one) can be bent when I rotate it in the pose mode(I want it to only be able to rotate in y axis). The bottom part, the cantilever, shouldn't be deformed and my top part deforms also badly when I rotate it in the y axis. Thank you

Comment: here's the blend file of the object http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33758

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so we have no idea what you did to this to get it this whacked out, but first of all, I went to the object menu, and cleared the armature from the table's parent.

Notice that the table flies across the entire world after doing this.

**IN OBJECT MODE** with no weight paints, or anything else going on, get the table and the armature in generally the same spot as each other using <kbd>G</kbd> (translate).

Next, select the table, *and then* the armature. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > *with automatic weights*. This fixes most of the problems.

You may need to do some veeery minor weight painting, but don't go overboard 'cause it's real easy to mess up with the weight paint.